How in recharts can you set the same intervals between points so as to keep the same width?
I am facing the following problem, I need to set equal intervals between the points on the x-axis, so as to keep the same interval widths(shown in the image). Now the interval widths are equal, but the interval values ​​are different.
example
Example with data and code:https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cllv8q
I tried a lot of options, but I still couldn't find an answer, maybe I'm not using some props of the recharts library, or in general, another library should be used that adapts to such data?

Your sandbox is not public or does not exist, can you make sure the permissions are correct?
